# Importing MySQL Data into Single Bootstrap Modal Box?

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Had such great success with my last question, thought I'd try another.

I'm building a "dashboard" for the company I work for, a printing facility.  This dashboard will list all of the current jobs in progress, jobs completed, etc. (It will really make life better for everyone there).

I have all of my customer information pulled from a MySQL Database using a PHP query and displayed into a DataTable using a PHP while loop.  I have an edit button at the end of each row that opens up a Modal box, displaying and allowing the printer to enter information and update the database.

This was working, but I began to think... all is well with only a handful of customers plugged in, but once we have 1,000+ customers, each given a Modal box (from the PHP while loop) it's going to get overwhelming.

Can anyone explain to me, if it is even possible, to have a single Modal Box code on the page that pulls the exact customer data into it when the link is clicked, launching the box.

**Button Launching The Modal (This is in a PHP while loop):**

```
<a class=\"btn btn-info\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#modal_id\"
href=\"display=" . $row['id'] . "\">
<i class=\"icon-question-sign icon-white\"></i>  
</a>
```

**Modal Code Itself (NOT in PHP while loop):**

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="modal_id">
   <div class="modal-header">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
       <h3>Project Details</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">

       ID is <?php echo $display ?>

   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
       <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save Changes</a>
       <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

The text inside just reads: ID is
The variable isn't being passed through the buttons href.

Any solutions?

Comment: Just looking for clarification. What you want is when a user clicks a row in your table (or a button associated with that row) then a modal appears that will contain data for ONLY that project. They could then close that modal and select a DIFFERENT project and the modal would reopen but with the new project's info. That correct?

Comment: Absolutely correct Nathan. My apologies if I wasn't very clear in the above description.

Comment: Did you get a chance to work with this anymore based on my answer? Any other issues or questions?

Comment: Hi Nathan, Your post pushed me to researching AJAX.  I haven't yet found a solution, but I now know what language I need to get this to work.  I am knowledgeable in HTML, CSS, PHP... but Javascript (and AJAX) I know next to nothing about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the most straightforward approach is AJAX.

1. Create an endpoint that you can pass an id to that will display the relevant projct info (something like yoursite/projects/5 would return data about project with ID of 5)
2. Use AJAX to send the ID to that endpoint and retrieve back the user data
3. Put that data into the modal as it's being displayed.

Change your links to buttons

```
<button class="project-button btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_id" data-project-id="<?=$row['id']?>">
  <i class="icon-question-sign icon-white"></i>  
</button>
```

Example of the AJAX call

```
var modal_body = $('#modal_id .modal-body');
$('.project_button').on('click', function() {
  var project_id = $(this).data('projectId');
  $.get('/project/', { id: project_id }, function(data) {
    // Populate modal
    modal_body.html(data);
  }
}
```

Obviously you would need to create the other page that creates the html that would get returned to be displayed. There are other things you could do like display a loading animation while the data gets loaded into the modal. But this should be a good starting point fo you.

Comment: Thanks to your example above, I was able to get the code working.  I can now display all of the information at the click of a button, without having to generate massive amounts of excess code.  Now that the information is populated in textareas, I need to learn how to update the information to send back to the database when a change was made.

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be using `AJAX`, so that you can pass `id` to another page of your choice

I found same problem being solved here with full explanation: http://thecomputerstudents.com/web/using-bootstrap-modal-ajax-import-data-mysql/